# Measuring current with an Arduino and op-amp circuit

Tags: arduino, voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-design, current-measurement

I want to do current measurement with a CT sensor and an Arduino with this [reference](https://circuitdiagrams.in/ac-current-measurement-using-arduino/).

This method seems to give more accurate results output in low current (video result.)

Previously I tried this [reference](https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/ct-sensors/introduction) from openenergymonitor, but it is still not as accurate as the first reference.

Based on the circuit design:

[image]

[image]

There are formulas with some variables I don't really understand.

> Vin = applied voltage of non-inverting terminal of op-amp

It's 970mV based on results of Vout in the reference.

Where does 970mV come from?

I will not get the Vout result if don't know the Vin.

Comment: Strange circuit. The capacitor has its polarity inverted and it only discharges through the diode leakage and bias current of the op. amp.

Comment: R1 for a CT should be 10 to 30 Ohm ... And this is not the best schematic if you want "linearity" ...

Comment: The SCT-013-030 version has an internal burden resistor to provide 0-1V for 0-30A. So the 22k resistor R1 is superfluous. Perhaps it is meant to be across the 100 uF capacitor, in which case the circuit will be essentially a peak hold with a decay TC of 2.2 seconds.

Comment: https://innovatorsguru.com/sct-013-000/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the behavior of this opamp circuit.
You shall note that the voltage gain in the linear portion is equal to ~ 11.
It is equal to your R3/R2 + 1 = 11.

This picture simulation shows 10.995, so it is ok.
You can see also the effect of temperature (0 °C, 25 °C, and 50 °C).
Also, see "errors" (non-linear curve below 25 mV input and above 250 mV).
Measuring with a diode into the circuit will also lead to some errors because of its nonlinearity.

[image]

And the behavior with the CT ...
One can see the non-linearity of voltage output versus input current.
Will add later the curve characteristic.

[image]